# How to fill Excel 2010 Cells with a recursion idea

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, vba

What I'm trying to do is have cells auto populate and un-populate dependent on the value of another cell.

For instance, Cell B3 has a set value of -0.1, Cell B4 has a set value of 0. Cell D3 is the cell im using as the control for the rest of the "B"cells. This is where things get complicated...

If the value of "1" is entered into cell D3 the sheet needs to auto fill Cells B5:B15 with a .1 interval.

If The value of "2" is entered into cell D3, the sheet needs to auto fill Cells B5:B25 with a .1 interval.

Most importantly if the value of "1" is entered into cell D3 the sheet needs to remove cells B16:B25. i would also be able to graph a sine wave on this function using the B value as the X axis.

Comment: Your best bet seems to be use data validation and private VBA functions rather than any formula

Answer (score 0):

In `B5` enter the following and fill down to `B15`.

```
=IF(OR($D$3=1,$D$3=2),B4+0.1,"")
```

In `B16` enter the following and fill down to `B25`.

```
=IF($D$3=2,B15+0.1,"")
```

**EDIT:**

Based on your comment, here is a more general solution. Just enter this in `B5` and fill down as far as you want/need.

```
=IF(ROW()-6<10*$D$3,B4+0.1,"")
```

Comment: how would i make this indefinite? such as so it would not break down where D3 = 10? is there some kind of switch logic or must i use nested ifs?

Comment: Sorry, it wasn't clear that you wanted it to work for more values than 1 and 2.